# CSRF verification , In django Templates

Tags: python, django, templates, csrf

I was trying to create a form in my custom template tag , and then try to create a HTML form there , and then simply use it inside my templates , but I'm getting the CSRF Verification Failed error , when the user submits the form ( and it's natural , cause I haven't provided the form inside the template tag with csrf_token ) , I did sth like this :

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def change_password_(context):
    csrf = context.get('csrf_token', '')
    html = "<form action='{% url change_password %}' method='post' id='renew_password' >"
    csrf_string = str(csrf)
    html += "<input type='hidden' value='%' />" %csrf_string
....
```

but still i'm getting the CSRF Verification failed error :( any idea how to make it work ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, try printing `csrf` in the template tag, or check the rendered html to make sure that the template tag is successfully getting the `csrf_token` from the template context.

Secondly, your csrf tag does not have a name attribute. Try the following:

```
html += "<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='%' />" %csrf_string
```

Finally, I would consider writing your template tag as an [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags). That will move the html to a separate template, which will look tidier. You can then use `{% csrf_token %}`
 in the tag's template file.

Comment: Seems the problem was that "name" attribute ,it worked when i added that :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking at a form I made using tempates I have this snippet:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<div style='display:none'><input type='hidden'  name='csrfmiddlewaretoken'
value='e987effa0c6ee111225a3c0edc927b06' /></div><table>
```

Maybe that will give you a idea how to put it directly in your markup

Comment: hmm, how could this be of any use when you have a static value for the token?

Comment: Of course, my token is of no use to the OP.  I just used my snippet as an example since the OP seemed to know how to get his own token.

Answer (score -2):

You need a `{% csrf_token %}` after the form tag, instead of the hidden input.

Read [this article](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/) for more information.

Comment: I'm doin this from a TemplateTag , It's not a Template(it's python code)